# Multivariate continuous wavelet transform

Tags: wavelets, time-series

I have used the continuous wavelet transform (CWT) and cross-wavelet transform (bivariate; XWT) several times while researching geophysical systems.

I'm trying to understand how the XWT can be extended to the multivariate case (more than two variables). I have seen some information to show how the Discrete Wavelet Transform can be undertaken for multivariate cases (Multiple wavelet correlation), but I have yet to find any guidance / material on CWT or XWT in a multivariate sense.

Is it not possible to extend continuous XWT to multivariate? If it is then any guidance / direction / materials would be incredibly helpful. Thanks.

Note: I am looking at the relationship between multiple indices of ocean/atmosphere systems (such as NAO, ENSO) on water resources at different frequencies.